# More than expected jobs running in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, pyspark

I am trying to learn apache-spark. This is my code which i am trying to run. I am using `pyspark api`.

```
data = xrange(1, 10000)
xrangeRDD = sc.parallelize(data, 8)
def ten(value):
  """Return whether value is below ten.

  Args:
      value (int): A number.

  Returns:
      bool: Whether `value` is less than ten.
  """
  if (value < 10):
      return True
  else:
      return False
filtered = xrangeRDD.filter(ten)

print filtered.collect()
print filtered.take(8)
```

`print filtered.collect()` gives this as output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

As per my understanding `filtered.take(n)` will take n elements from RDD and print it.

I am trying two cases :-

1)Giving value of n less than or equal to number of elements in RDD

2)Giving value of n greater than number of elements in RDD

I have `pyspark application UI` to see number of jobs that run in each case. In first case only `one job` is running but in second `five jobs` are running.

I am not able to understand why is this happening.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RDD.take` tries to evaluate as few partitions as possible.

If you `take(9)` it will fetch partition 0 (job 1) find 9 items and happily terminate.

If you `take(10)` it will fetch partition 0 (job 1) and find 9 items. It needs one more. Since partition 0 had 9, it thinks partition 1 will probably have at least one more (job 2). But it doesn't! In 2 partitions it has found 9 items. So 4.5 items per partition so far. The formula divides it by 1.5 for pessimism and decides 10 / (4.5 / 1.5) = 3 partitions will do it. So it fetches partition 2 (job 3). Still nothing. So 3 items per partition so far, divided by 1.5 means we need 10 / (3 / 1.5) = 5 partitions. It fetches partitions 3 and 4 (job 4). Nothing. We have 1.8 items per partition, 10 / (1.8 / 1.5) = 8. It fetches the last 3 partitions (job 5) and that's it.

The code for this algorithm is in [RDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1146). As you can see it's nothing but heuristics. It saves some work usually, but it can lead to unnecessarily many jobs in degenerate cases.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me. I am still very new to spark so this will take some time to understand fully. But i think i am getting your reply.

Comment: Let me know if a part is unclear. If you want to understand this fully I think the source code is the best resource though. (You don't have to understand this, however, to use Apache Spark effectively!)

Comment: This is my understanding so far. `xrangeRDD` is a RDD with 8 partitions. When `collect` action is performed then spark will run jobs on all 8 partitions and form filtered RDD. But when i perform `take` action then it will run job only on that much partitions which give demanded elements. In first case since demanded elements were `9` and fulfilled by first partition it stops. But when they are more than `9` it carry on to other partitions till solution is not found or there is no more partition. Please correct me where i am wrong.